# is it wrong to say "I talk English"?

Tags: word-usage

Ok, most of the time we hear people say "**speak English**" such as "*I speak English very well*", "*He can't speak English*", etc.

I searched on the internet & it says "**talk**" is synonym of "**speak**" [Source](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3Atalk)

However, but I seldom hear anyone says "**talk English**" such as "*I talk English very well*", "*He can't talk English*", etc.

So, *is it wrong to say "**I talk English**"?*

Comment: Here's **[an answer that touches on this topic](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/218514/48335)**, although the question there is different.

Comment: Here some more explanation: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/speak-or-talk

Comment: see ngram, people do say "talk English" since 18th century https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=speak+English%2C+talk+English&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cspeak%20English%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctalk%20English%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Looking at COHA, there's already an example of an author using "talk English" as an example of at least very awkward, if not incorrect, speech in 1820. If the two phrases really were somewhat interchangeable in 1740, they certainly diverged fast.

Comment: There are only two situations I can imagine where a native speaker would use "talk English" - if they were ironically using incorrect/non-standard grammar (e.g. "Me fail English? That's unpossible!") or if they were using the Amish idiom of "English" as a generic name for non-Amish(e.g. "Well go on then and talk, English".

Comment: "I talk English" is wrong if you are referring to English as a language. [We use speak when referring to languages](https://youtu.be/g0j2dVuhr6s?t=58s). The problem with Ngrams is they don't tell you much about the context. If you look on the web a LOT of the "I talk English" content is by folks who speak English as a foreign language, and if you look at samples of the books if you compare "I talk English" to "I speak English" with Google Ngrams, they seem to be about people whose first language isn't English.

Comment: "Talk English!" is used as an imperative. It's somewhat patronizing, and would show up either as direction to a foreigner, or to someone who was in some other way incomprehensible. Neither use is polite, and you probably want to avoid both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You provided your own Ngram in [a comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/79427/is-it-wrong-to-say-i-talk-english/79432#comment153434_79427).

[image]

It is not wrong, but as your own Ngram suggests it is not common—especially in the last 55 years. As a native speaker I would say it is not idiomatic today to say *I talk English* when you mean that you know how to communicate orally in English. For that I would use and recommend *I speak English*.